# Templates for designing neural network architectures

Tags: neural-network, visualization

I trying to produce a neural network visualization similar to the one below ([link](https://github.com/cbaziotis/datastories-semeval2017-task4/blob/master/task4A-1.png)):

[image]

I was wondering if anybody could suggest any resources that they have used themselves and are happy with. If, in particular, anyone knows of any freely available template from which I can build off, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to e-mail the author who let me know that he used **Powerpoint** for this one. Who would have thought!